# Chromium crashes when clicking on a link in Thunderbird

Tags: nvidia, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, thunderbird

I have a small problem, every time when i click on a link in Thunderbird or any other application (like Discord), Chromium opens then a new window and says that Chromium didn't shut down correctly and asks me if i want to restore it.

This occurs not all the time, but when it happens all the Bookmarks are not having a favicon and the extensions (listed below) are not loaded or without a configuration. I tried to re-install Chromium, sadly with no success.

Extensions:

- LastPass
- OmegaProxy
- Vanilla
- HTTPSeverywhere

Chromium version: 52.0.2743.116

Laptop:

- MEM: 16GB
- CPU: Intel Core i7-4720HQ
- GPU: GeForce GTX 960M

[image]

Comment: Apparently you have a corrupt profile. Try deleting it and start over. It should be located inside .config. Reinstalling in this scenario is just a wrong move stemming from a Windows way that isn't applicable.